# Hide grid lines for second series in AChartEngine

Tags: android, achartengine

How do I hide the second scale's grid lines in a combined xy chart with multiple XYSeries and time series. I only want to show the grid lines for the first scale.

Markus

Comment: What do you mean for `second series grid lines`? Can you be more clear?

Comment: Its good to elaborate the question for better answer

Comment: I have 4 series in the chart, three series map to the left y-axis (scale index 0) and one series is added to the right y-axis (using new XYSeries(title, scale);) where scale is set to 1. I want to show grid lines for the left y-axis, but not for the right one.

Comment: The grid lines can only be hidden per axis, not per scale.

Comment: Ok, so if I have two y-axises, how do I hide the grid lines for the right y-axis?